# Simple contract question, am I the owner?

Tags: contract-development

I started a contract through etherscan's publish and verify. But the contract hash it isn't under my verified address? Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting contract owner, if the contract does not assign his own ownership explicitly to someone, is the EOA who paid  the gas for the deployment.

This does not mean that he is enabled to modify the contract or to kill it or whatever, because possible code details. In particular the originator of the contract can/must store this property at deploy time in order to access it, I.e. to be recognized by the contract as the owner in any further interaction (after deploy time).

The ownership property is intrinsic to Ethereum environment and remains anyway fully accessible for other environment operations, like to verify the contracts versus the code in etherscan and so on.

Comment: I'd think this is a Etherscan question and not so much about contract functionaliy (contract ownership). Furthermore there is no explicit "owner" property for contracts so nobody owns contracts unless there is some coded ownership functionality.